# How to resolve Unexpected token error while importing ChatBot in React Native Web app

Tags: react-native, chatbot, react-native-web

I am creating chatbot web app using React-Native. I am beginner for react-native. If anyone has idea on this issue please let me know where I am wrong.

I am using this library -
https://github.com/LucasBassetti/react-native-chatbot

I follow this steps -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5A70BUygUE

I am getting an error -

```
./node_modules/react-native-chatbot/lib/ChatBot.js
SyntaxError: /Users/anil/Documents/myApp/node_modules/react-native-chatbot/lib/ChatBot.js: Unexpected token (426:8)

  424 |     if (component && !asMessage) {
  425 |       return (
> 426 |         <CustomStep
      |         ^
  427 |           key={index}
  428 |           delay={customDelay}
  429 |           step={step}
```

Here is my code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChatBot from 'react-native-chatbot' 
import {
  StyleSheet,
 // Text,
  View,

} from 'react-native';

const steps = [
  {
    id: '0',
    message: 'Welcome to react chatbot!',
    trigger: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    message: 'Bye!',
    end: true,
  },
];

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  //  backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  text:{
    fontSize : 25
  }
});

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ChatBot steps={steps} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

These are the dependancies added -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.x",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-art": "^16.6.x",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.x",
    "react-http-request": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-chatbot": "0.0.1-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "^0.10.x",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not a react but regular javascript sytanx error. What you are trying to do in the following is to return some HTML code in a javascript function.

```
  render() {

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>   // <View> is a HTML/XML tag/keyword

        <ChatBot steps={steps} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I believe these tags are not part of java script syntax and you need to return them as a string instead. Some thing like following should work.

```
  render() {

     return (
      `<View style={styles.container}>

        <ChatBot steps={steps} />
      </View>`
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: I tried above code but it's not worked in my case. @Ahsun Ali

Comment: The above mentioned error message is same. Added with couple of errors to the imported libraries ex- React' is declared but its value is never read. ChatBot' is declared but its value is never read. @Ahsun Ali

Comment: @TejasRatunawar Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @Sue Yeah I have resolved this problem but my bad, I don't have that code handy. Sorry !!

Comment: how to solve ? can you help me i found the same error